# C - consumer/producer appears deadlock when producer bigger than buffer size

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, semaphore, producer-consumer

I have assignment to work on producer and consumer problem by use thread and semaphore.  The task is that allow user to define # of producer,# of consumer and buffer size.  The program always lock if producer reach the buffersize. But the requirement says if producer reach buffersiz the consumer thread should start and take things from buffer.  I am out of idea how to fix this problem and my teacher refuse to help.  I am a totally beginner of the C language, please give me some suggestion. Thank you very much

My program can run when Producer = Consumer, or Producer < Consumer, except Producer > Buffer Size, it seems to appear deadlock, and I think I understand the reason why but I don't know how to fix the code to let Consumer thread run first than back to Producer thread.

Here is the running result when producer =3  consumer = 1 and buffersize = 2

```
./Task2 3 1 2
Producer 0 has started
Producer 0:Put item 0.
Producer 1 has started
Producer 1:Put item 1.
Producer 2 has started
```

The requirement says the result should looks like

```
Started
Producer 0 has started
Producer 0: Put item 0.
Producer 1 has started
Producer 1: Put item 1.
Producer 2 has started
Consumer 0 has started
Consumer 0: Taked item 0.
Producer 2: Put item 2.
Terminated!
```

Here is my origional code, I have discard some input error check code

```
#include <pthread.h> 
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <semaphore.h>

pthread_t *pid, *cid;

void *producer(void *param); 
void *consumer(void *param); 
void init();
int Remove();

struct prot_buffer{
int Producer;
int Consumer;
int *buffer;        
int buffersize;
int front;      
int rear;           
int item;           
sem_t mutex;        
sem_t slots;
sem_t items;
}b;


main(int argc, char *argv[]){
int c1; 

b.Producer = atoi(argv[1]);
b.Consumer = atoi(argv[2]);
b.buffersize = atoi(argv[3]);

init(); 

pid = (pthread_t *)malloc(b.Producer *sizeof(pthread_t));
cid = (pthread_t *)malloc(b.Consumer *sizeof(pthread_t));

for (c1=0; c1< b.Producer; c1++){
    printf("Producer %d has started\n", c1);
    pthread_create(&(pid[c1]),NULL, producer, NULL);
    pthread_join(pid[c1], NULL);
    printf("Producer %d:Create item %d.\n", c1,c1);
}


/* Create the consumer threads */
for (c1=0; c1<b.Consumer; c1++){
    printf("Consumer %d has started\n", c1);
    pthread_create(&(cid[c1]),NULL, consumer, NULL);
        if (b.front==b.rear){
        printf("Terminated!\n");
        exit(0);
        }  
    pthread_join(cid[c1], NULL);
    printf("Consumer %d:Taked item %d.\n", c1, c1);
}  

free(b.buffer);
free(pid);
free(cid);

sem_destroy(&b.items);
sem_destroy(&b.slots);
sem_destroy(&b.mutex);

printf("Threads terminated!\n");
exit(0);
}

void *producer(void *param){
sem_wait(&b.slots);                             sem_wait(&b.mutex);

if(b.rear<=b.buffersize){
    b.buffer[b.rear] = b.item; 
    b.rear++;
    sem_post(&b.mutex);                             sem_post(&b.items);                     
}else{
sem_post(&b.mutex);                             sem_post(&b.items);                             }
}

void *consumer(void *param){
Remove();
}

void init(){
b.buffer = (int *) malloc(b.buffersize *sizeof(int));
b.buffersize = b.buffersize;
b.front = b.rear =0;
sem_init(&b.items, 0, 0);
sem_init(&b.slots,0,b.buffersize);
sem_init(&b.mutex, 0, 1);
}

int Remove(){
sem_wait(&b.items);                     
sem_wait(&b.mutex);                     

b.item = b.buffer[b.front];             
b.front++;

sem_post(&b.mutex);                     
sem_post(&b.slots);                     
return b.item;
}
```

My new code

```
main(int argc, char *argv[]){
...

pthread_create(&pid,NULL, producer, NULL);
pthread_create(&cid,NULL, consumer, NULL);
....
}

void *producer(void *param){
int c2;

for (c2=0; c2 < b.Producer; c2++) {
printf("Producer %d has started\n", c2);
b.item = c2;

sem_wait(&b.slots);
sem_wait(&b.mutex); 

b.buffer[b.rear] = b.item;
b.rear = (b.rear+1)%b.buffersize;
printf("Producer %d:Put item %d.\n", c2,c2);

sem_post(&b.mutex);
sem_post(&b.items);

}
return NULL;
}

void *consumer(void *param){
int c2;

for (c2=0; c2 < b.Consumer; c2++) {
printf("Consumer %d has started\n", c2,c2);
b.item = c2;

sem_wait(&b.items);
sem_wait(&b.mutex); 

b.buffer[b.front] = b.item;
b.front = (b.front+1)%b.buffersize;

printf("Consumer %d:take item %d.\n", c2, c2);

sem_post(&b.mutex);
sem_post(&b.slots);

}
return NULL;
}
```

To avoid trobule at school I remove some code and some description.

The program result is correct now, thanks for help.  In this case I use b.item as the variable to display the item left inside the buffer, but its wrong.  Use other variable like front or rear also not work too.

Program result-

Producer=2, Consumer=2, Buffer=2

```
./F 2 2 2
started
Producer 0 has started
Producer 0:Put item 0.
Producer 1 has started
Producer 1:Put item 1.
Consumer 0 has started
Consumer 0:Take item 0.
Consumer 1 has started
Consumer 1:Take item 1.
1 item(s) left in the buffer!  //This is wrong!
Terminated!
```

Producer=3, Consumer=1, Buffer=2

```
./F 3 1 2
started
Producer 0 has started
Producer 0:Deposited item 0.
Producer 1 has started
Producer 1:Deposited item 1.
Producer 2 has started
Consumer 0 has started
Consumer 0:Removed item 0.
Producer 2:Deposited item 2.
0 item(s) left in the buffer!  //Still wrong!
Terminated!
```

Producer =2, Consumer = 5, Buffer =3

```
./F 2 5 3
started
Producer 0 has started
Producer 0:Put item 0.
Producer 1 has started
Producer 1:Put item 1.
Consumer 0 has started
Consumer 0:Take item 0.
Consumer 1 has started
Consumer 1:Take item 1.
Consumer 2 has started
2 item(s) left in the buffer!  //Wrong again!
Terminated!
```

Comment: Casting the return value of `malloc` is unnecessary.

Comment: Are you constrained to use semaphore? Can't you use conditional variables? They seem to be a much more natural choice for this situation.

Comment: @Tudor  yes, the requirement of task  said we must use semaphore.

Comment: The use of semaphores for producer-consumers queues is an absoultely standard 'Computer Science 101' approach.  The OP use of them is correct too but, sadly, the manipulation of the buffer indexes and a nasty case of premature enjoinification has caused problems.

Comment: @ShawnLien I've added a link to my answer which might be quite useful to you. Check out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your buffer size is 2. The first 2 producers fill up this buffer. Hence the third one is waiting for a consumer to take one item so that it can add to buffer. **But your `pthread_join` inside the producer loop never allows for consumers to be created at all!** `pthread_join` is suspending `main` process until 3rd producer terminates. Hence the deadlock where in the third Producer is indefinitely waiting for the buffer to be freed by a consumer who never arrives.

I suggest you go through [Exercise 3](http://www.csc.villanova.edu/~mdamian/threads/posixsem.html) of this article which deals with exactly the same problem and the same data structure as yours. They've clearly articulated how to prevent buffer overflow, where to print producer data. May be its a standard semaphore tutorial exercise for grads.

Comment: +1 for the join() disaster.  Sadly, many developers, (and threading examples), seem to rush to join() with threads as soon as possible, irrespective of whether any other approach might avoid the perils of hard-lock join() and similar deadlock-generators.

Comment: @Martin James  Thanks alot,the exercise is really helpful. Before I also notice the problem cause by _join() but I dont know how to correct my program.  I have rewrite my program base on the exercise and the result looks fine but still have some problem.  It seems the producer thread not sleep long enough and start to loop again, from my two new 2 results I notice the producer will keep create even there is no more buffer space.  Can you tell me where should I correct my code? If there is 3 producer the producer should create exactly 3 times rather than loop again and again. Thanks alot

Comment: @ShawnLien I am quite busy right now, I'll do come back and edit my answer to give you further pointers in code

Comment: I found the problem, just becuase for loop create multi thread.  I have correct it, now it can display the correct number of producer and consumer.  But I meet new problem, I dont no which variable should use to display the item left in buffer. I try rear,front,and item but non of it can display correctly.  For example if producer =3, consumer =1, after program terimate there should be 2 items left inside the buffer, but if I use rear as variable it always show 1 item left inside buffer.  I think the reason is because the %buffersize in both metod, but I'm not sure know how to make it right

Answer (score 0):

Your initialization and use of the semaphores seems correct - they are a natural choice for producer-consumer queues - it's condvars that are not, (condvars have no count and so require while loops for correct operation even if your OS does not support the spurious wakeup feature).

Your use of the buffer, however, seems a bit 'off'.  I presume that the buffer is supposed to be circular? If so, you should be setting the index back to 0 whenever the front, or rear, index reaches the end of the array.  You should be doing this inside the mutex lock in both the producer and consumer code.  The check on the indexes should be solely to reset them to the start of the buffer and should not change the operation of the semaphore signal/wait in any way.

That, and you seem to be joining the threads as soon as they are created.  Usually, to test/demonstrate producer/consumer operation, threads are not continually created, immediately joined, (so that the constructing thread has to immediately wait), and then left to terminate.  It's more common to run up some producer and consumer threads that loop, continually producing/consuming messages, (perhaps with a very short sleep loop - those kind of loops that some developers say have no valid use and are an anti-pattern).

Continually creating/terminating/destroying threads is very wasteful and will result, in your test code, in an app that is performing nearly all overhead and very little producer/consumer.

Last thing - don't join to threads without thinking about it for a second or two first.  It may not be optimal, it may not be necessary, it may be a hindrance, it may be a disaster.  If the join is solely to keep your main thread, (and so process), from terminating early, it may be better to find another way - wait on keyboard input or use a long-term sleep() loop.